# Поиск файла по номеру кластера на диске

Tags: winapi, любой-язык, файловая-система

С клавиатуры вводится номер кластера. Необходимо выяснить, какому из файлов выделен данный кластер, и вывести имя этого файла.

Вообще вопрос как это сделать? с чего начать? Желательно на win 32 api, но можно и на питоне или шарпах.

Comment: связанный вопрос [How can I find information about a file from logical cluster number in NTFS/FAT32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2493901/4279)

Comment: по ссылке рекомендуют FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для NTFS-дисков начиная с Windows 7, как [отметил jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753833/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5/801449#comment1163645_753833), можно использовать [FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff951637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (требует привилегий администратора).

Пример на С++:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

/*Вывод сообщения об ошибке*/
void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);

}

/*Отображение информации о файле, расположенном в указанном кластере указанного тома*/
BOOL FindFileByClaster(TCHAR* volume,LONGLONG cluster){

    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(volume,      // drive to open
        GENERIC_READ ,                       // access to the drive
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  // share mode
        NULL,                                // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,                       // disposition
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,          // file attributes
        NULL);

    if(hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {   
          ErrorMes(L"CreateFile");
          return FALSE;
    }

    //входные параметры
    LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_INPUT input={0};
    input.NumberOfClusters = 1;
    input.Cluster[0].QuadPart = cluster;        

    //буфер для результатов
    BYTE output[5000]={};
    DWORD dwRes=0;
    LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT result={0};   

    //пытаемся отправить IOCTL...
    BOOL bRes = DeviceIoControl( (HANDLE)       hDevice,   // handle to file, directory, or volume 
                 FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER, // dwIoControlCode
                 (LPVOID)       &input,        // input buffer 
                 (DWORD)        sizeof(input),     // size of input buffer 
                 (LPVOID)       output,       // output buffer 
                 (DWORD)        5000,    // size of output buffer 
                 (LPDWORD)      &dwRes,   // number of bytes returned 
                 NULL );    // OVERLAPPED structure

    if(bRes == FALSE){      
          ErrorMes(L"DeviceIoControl");
          return FALSE;
    }

    //переносим результат из массива в структуру LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT
    memcpy(&result,output,sizeof(LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_OUTPUT));

    if(result.NumberOfMatches == 0){
        wprintf( L"Файл не найден\n");
        return FALSE;
    }   

    wprintf( L"Информация о файле\n");

    //переходим к адресу первой структуры LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY
    BYTE* p = (BYTE*)output + result.Offset;
    LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY* pentry = (LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY*)p;    

    //выводим информацию
    wprintf( L"Flags: 0x%x ",(UINT)pentry->Flags);

    if((pentry->Flags & LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY_FLAG_PAGE_FILE) > 0) wprintf(L"(Pagefile)");
    else if((pentry->Flags & LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY_FLAG_FS_SYSTEM_FILE) > 0)  wprintf(L"(Internal filesystem file)");
    else if((pentry->Flags & LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER_ENTRY_FLAG_TXF_SYSTEM_FILE) > 0) wprintf(L"(Internal TXF file)");
    else wprintf(L"(Normal file)"); 

    wprintf( L"\nFile: %s\n",pentry->FileName); 
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    LONGLONG inp=0;
    wprintf( L"Введите номер кластера: \n");
    scanf("%llu",&inp);

    FindFileByClaster(L"\\\\.\\C:",inp);        

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Данный пример выводит имя потока, чтобы получить имя файла, нужно взять часть до вхождения строки "::" (например, до префикса`::$DATA`).

Answer (score 1):

Преподаватель или работодатель, который дал такое задание, или жестоко постебался, или автор вопроса рассказал какой он супер-спец и ему дали задание под стать его рассказам. Для выполнения этого задания требуются достаточно специфичные знания. Но судя по вопросу, у автора вопроса нету даже начальных знаний, поэтому дальше можно не читать.

Для тех же, кто наткнется на этот вопрос спустя много лет и тоже будет озадачен чем-то таким, то:

1. Спрашиваем пользователя о номере кластера и устройстве (предполагается, что опрос оборудования и гуй к нему человек уже умеет делать, равно как и открывать устройства, как дали пример в соседнем ответе)
2. Определяем тип файловой системы, благо не так много систем, где есть понятие "кластер", а метка "винапи" сужает их всего до 3х штук (известных мне на данный момент). Можно по сигнатуркам, но в самих спеках Мелкософт советует так не делать, а обращать внимание на значения в тех или иных полях загрузочного сектора.
3. Парсим файловую структуру всего диска. Для НТФС достаточно просто зачитать весь МФТ и найти где же там нужный кластер, для ФАТов придется побегать по дереву директорий, пока не найдем нужное. Ну и что нашли, то и выводим на экран

Как видим, все в общем-то просто. Осталось прочитать несколько спецификаций страниц эдак на 200-300 и тупо реализовать. Я нечто подобное делал несколько месяцев, но так и не доделал, запрокрастинировав свой проект.

Если бы я был соискателем работы, то такое тестовое задание бы служило индикатором, что работодатель действительно хороший, а не очередная шарага. Но знания, которые тут потребуются, достаточно специфичные. Я бы очень долго искал, чем же на самом деле занимается такая конторка, прежде чем туда зааплаиться.

Comment: благодарю за ответ, да действительно у меня нет знаний в низкоуровневом программировании, а это задание моей лабораторной)

Comment: ну и при чем здесь тег питона в вопросе?!

Comment: может это можно на питоне сделать а не на win api

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода открытия на низком уровне диска я привел. Дальше Вам нужно разобраться какой тип файловой системы у вас в наличии и по таблицам файловой системы определять принадлежность кластера.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    HANDLE H = CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
    if(H == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
          DWORD err = GetLastError();
          std::cout << "Не удалось открыть диск!" << std::endl;
                  return 1;   
    }
    CloseHandle(H);
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Настоятельно рекомендую сначала почитать о системной программировании под windows. например http://bydlokoder.ru/index.php?p=books_WinAPI

Comment: хорошо, ну вот допустим флешка fat32, получается в 12 строчке я ввожу номер, и после 12 я должен как то определить чей это кластер? а как в 4 строке понять какой именно я диск открыл?

Comment: В примере функция открывает физический диск. Если влом определять каким диском является флэшка. Используй логические имена \\.\<БукваДиска>        Функция откроет диск как файл и дальше уже работаешь с содержимым файла. А дальше открываешь сссылку http://samag.ru/archive/article/245  "куришь ее". Потом открываешь ссылку https://dev64.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/reading-fat32-in-windows/ вдохновляешься примером работы c fat и пишешь программу для решения твоей задачи